# Preservation of eigenspaces for commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

**Question** I am trying to proof something for normal matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. I have stumbled upon this "if and only if" condition for commuting matrices. I think I have proven it, could someone verify whether my proof is correct?

> **Lemma** *Let $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ with $A$ diagonizable. Then $AB=BA$ if and only if all eigenspaces of $A$ are
>   $B$-invariant.*
>
> *Proof:* Let $A$ and $B$ be as in the lemma. $AB=BA$ is equivalent to $(A-\lambda I_n)B=B(A-\lambda I_n)$. Let $E_\lambda$ be an eigenspace
>   of $A$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$.
>
> Assuming $A$ and $B$ commute, we find  $$((A-\lambda I_n)B)E_\lambda = (B(A-\lambda I_n))E_\lambda = B(\{0\}) = \{0\}$$ which implies that
>   $B(E_\lambda)\subseteq E_\lambda$ because $(A-\lambda I_n)|_{E_\mu}$
>   is injective for $\mu\neq\lambda$ and $\mu\in\sigma(A)$ and
>   eigenvalue.
>
> For the other direction we assume $B(E_\lambda)\subseteq E_\lambda$.
>   Using the same equation from the first direction again, we find that
>   $$((A-\lambda I_n)B)|_{E_\lambda}=(B(A-\lambda I_n))|_{E_\lambda}\equiv 0$$ for all
>   $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$. Because
>   $\mathbb{K}^n=\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}E_\lambda$ we find that
>   $(A-\lambda I_n)B=B(A-\lambda I_n)$. This proofs that $A$ and $B$
>   commute.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts thanks. The implication / equals mistake was due to formatting. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to explain in the last paragraph why $((A-\lambda I_n)B)|_{E_\mu}=(B(A-\lambda I_n))|_{E_\mu}$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks! I corrected $\mu$ by replacing it by $\lambda$ and I wrote the two linear maps are equal because they are the zero-map when looking at the restriction for the respective eigenspace.